# Go higher order functions

Tags: go

I am trying to understand higher order functions in Go. I have the following program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func caller(foo func(string) string) {
    result := foo("David")
    fmt.Println(result)
}

bar := func(name string) string {
    return "Hello " + name
}

func main(){
    caller(bar)
}
```

When I run it:

> go run higher_order_functions.go

It gives the following error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./higher_order_functions.go:10:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
./higher_order_functions.go:11:5: syntax error: unexpected return, expecting )
```

I am expecting the output:

> "Hello David"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:= assignment doesn’t work outside of function bodies.

You have to use var bar = instead.

Answer (score 1):

Short variable declaration doesn't work outside of function body, here is more [information](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) about it.

Working solution to your problem could be something like below,

```js
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
 caller(bar)
}

func caller(foo func(string) string) {
 result := foo("David")
 fmt.Println(result)
}

func bar(s string) string {
 return "Hello " + s
}
```